# Setting up a constructor that makes an Ajax call and also templates data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a constructor object that will output some slides, in this constructor I've worked out I will need to make an Ajax call to get some data and then template out the returned data. I'm thinking maybe the data needs to be returned outside the constructor and then passed as a param? Just not completely sure right now how this should be constructed, what is the best approach for this? Or maybe do I pass in a data url to a getData method in my constructor

Comment: Usually, you do not want to have a constructor doing asynchronous things because it complicates returning errors and values and makes returning a promise difficult.  You end up having the pass a callback into the constructor.  The usual solution is to construct the object and then making a method call on it that does whatever async things need doing.

Comment: Ok, so something like var slider = new Slider(); then do a var data = slider.getData(); then on done slider.templateData(data) something like this?

Comment: Call `getData` in `init`, then inside `getData` you have to wait for the response (callback or promise), call `templateData` on the response, `this.el.innerHTML` the HTML and then `bindUI`. Seems pretty straight forward. --- Oh, wait. Those are supposed to be public methods. Why? Is there any chance you'll need to call them in a different order? Or maybe instead of `getData` you'd use an external source? Then why put it in your `Slider` "class" at all?

Comment: Updated my code there as it was incorrect, really right now I just need to find out the best approach for something like this, should I be chaining everything inside the constructor or doing it individually when I instantiate the class

Comment: try this object with little chained methods on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fipeharexo/2/edit?js,console,output)